# node.js require method can't find javascript file: Module not found

Tags: node.js

I am very new to node.js and i am follwing a few different tutorials. My goal is to use node with ejs or underscore. My first attempt with using underscore isn't going really well.

I am using `bower` to manage script dependencies for my project and i was able to pull down the the amd version of underscore under the path `public/javascripts/vendor`. I am confident that if i were to install underscore using `npm`, the module would be found and the error would go away.

I thought setting the app.config with this line

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

essentially uses all static files under that directory? How come then, underscore can't be found..

This i how i am using it by the way.

```
   var _ = require('underscore-amd');
app.register('.html', {
    compile: function(str, options){
        var compiled = require('underscore-amd').template(str);
        return function(locals) {
            return compiled(locals);
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention npm, so that is the correct way to use underscore in node:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "*",
  }
}
```

Bower is for client-side, and you can't (easily) use a bower lib in node.

This is for serving static files to client:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

not for use by node on the server-side.

Comment: so if i want to use underscore, i will have duplicate dependencies. one for the server and the other for the client?

Comment: Yes. Though note if you really want to manage and use identical deps on client and server, you may want to try browserify: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify.   This allows you to bundle up npm modules for use in the client (basically the inverse of what you tried.)